# How can I set valid value to visual bell?

Tags: vim, command

I want to get a visual bell in my mvim. I set `:set vb` to get the visual bell. However, the flash is not obvious because the flash duration is too short.

According to the help:

> In the GUI, 't_vb' defaults to "|f", which inverts the display
>       for 20 msec.  If you want to use a different time, use "|40f",
>       where 40 is the time in msec.

So the default 20 msec is short, I want to change it to a longer time.

My problem is I couldn't set the value of 't_vb' to a valid value:

- I set by press Ctrl-V then Esc then |100f, vim complaint with "Invalid Argument"
- I set like `:set t_vb="<Esc>|100f"`, vim did not complain but it didn't work either.

How can I set the value for 't_vb' properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `|`

Like so:

`:set t_vb=^[\|100f`

(where `^[` is entered by using `Ctrl-V` followed by `Esc`.)

Comment: yes, it was because I forgot the escaping. It works now, thank you, Peter.